# How to write a multi-command alias in xonsh?

Tags: shell, xonsh

In bash and zsh I used to write:

```
alias nb='cd /home/lincoln/Dropbox/nupis/ && jupyter notebook'
```

But in xonsh this returns an error saying that the command was not found. 
The [tutorial's](http://xon.sh/tutorial.html) section on aliases says that I should do something like:

```
aliases['g'] = 'git status -sb'
```

I could make this work in the case of only one command, but when I try the two commands of my bash example, it complains that I am giving too many inputs to `cd`.

Note: I know I could import the alias from the other shells, but I am interested in learning to do this in xonsh.

Comment: This works fine in recent versions of xonsh.

Answer (score 9):

@lincolnfrias, xonsh does not yet have support for string aliases that have multiple commands.  This is a bug / deficiency that will hopefully be addressed soon.  Until then, though, you can use a function alias for this behaviour.

```
def _nb(args, stdin=None):
    cd /home/lincoln/Dropbox/nupis/ && jupyter notebook

aliases['nb'] = _nb
```

Or if you really wanted to do this in one line:

```
aliases['nb'] = lambda a, s: ![cd /home/lincoln/Dropbox/nupis/] and ![jupyter notebook]
```

Comment: Thanks for using it!

Answer (score 0):

Separating commands with `;` works fine, as in:

`aliases['gp'] = 'git add -A :/; git commit -m asdf;git push;'`

Answer (score 0):

Aliases which are a single string are evaluated as though they were typed, so you can chain commands using `;`, `&&`, etc.

You can access the arguments passed to the alias as `$args` in a Python context, i.e. `@($args)`. Note the dollar sign is *inside* the parenthesis!

For example:

```
robmee01@C02F2508MD6R:~
@ aliases['nb'] = 'echo cd /home/lincoln/Dropbox/nupis/ && echo jupyter notebook @($args)'
```

Sample usage:

```
user@host:~ @ nb --option1 --option2
cd /home/lincoln/Dropbox/nupis/
jupyter notebook --option1 --option2
```

The guide I've found most useful: [anki-code/xonsh-cheatsheet: Cheat sheet for xonsh shell with copy-pastable examples. The best doc for the new users.](https://github.com/anki-code/xonsh-cheatsheet#aliases)